# Get sum of column values for specific rows only | Get sum of sales for each country

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I am super new to power bi and Dax and i need to create a calculated column in which i have the total sales for each country respectively.

Here is a screenshot with an oversimplified scenario but if i can do it for this data i can do it in my actual project since the concept is the same.
The column TotalSalesPerCountry is the calculated column.

[image]

And here is what the column should look like if it worked. (Colors are just for visual representation)

[image]

Basically everywhere you see the same country you should see the same TotalSalesPerCountry values which are calculated by sum-ing the Sales for those countries over the years.

Comment: If an option, you can do this easily in Power Query (`Home=>Transform Data`) by grouping and aggregating by Sum.  Then re-expand and sort by Year.  If the original order is required, add an Index column before you group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple to do in DAX. Add the column:

```
TotalSalesPerCountry = 
var curCountry = yourTable[Country]
return CALCULATE(SUM(Sales), FILTER(yourTable, curCountry = yourTable[Country]))
```

Explanation:
For each row in the table, get the country. Filter yourTable on the curCountry and SUM this together).

Answer (score 2):

Another DAX function:

```
= CALCULATE(SUM(CountrySales[Sales]), FILTER(CountrySales, CountrySales[Country] = EARLIER (CountrySales[Country])))
```